# foundation panels style issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

for some reason, the subsequent panels on this page get bigger like a pyramid even though they're identical.  I want them to be the same width, even if they have to be a different height due to the amount of text.  I'm using Foundation 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/jenborn/At8jz/

PHP

```
$pt1="1.  This is a test";
$pt2="2.  This is a test";
$pt3="3.  This is a test";
$pt4="4.  This is a test";
```

HTML

```
<div class="row"><div class="small-3 small-centered columns"><h3 id="makemebold" class="subheader">This is how it works:</h3></div></div>

  <div class="row"><div class="small-6 small-centered columns"><div class="panel" ><h5><? echo $pt1 ?></h5></div></div>
  <div class="row"><div class="small-6 small-centered columns"><div class="panel" ><h5><? echo $pt2 ?></h5></div></div>
  <div class="row"><div class="small-6 small-centered columns"><div class="panel" ><h5><? echo $pt3 ?></h5></div></div>
  <div class="row"><div class="small-6 small-centered columns"><div class="panel" ><h5><? echo $pt4 ?></h5></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's setting the width of each panel as a percentage of the `.row` class. You can remove the `.row` wrapper in this case since the panels are already wraped in a div: http://jsfiddle.net/At8jz/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 small-centered columns">
        <h3 id="makemebold" class="subheader">This is how it works:</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <h5>This is a test</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    ... other panels ...

</div>
```